# Making a server side API Call

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a question about how the API's on my website work. There's a specific way that I want my site to work. 
So I currently have a website that runs an API request from a JavaScript file and then that JS file loads the data into the HTML. My question is, when my users navigate to the website, are each of their devices making an api call, or is it being made once on the server?
I would like for the call to be made a single time on the server and be stored there. Then when someone navigates to my site they're device only requests the data from the server that the data is stored on. (I want to use other APIs that have a very low call limit, which is why I want to find a way to do this) And preferably achieve this using only JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of your website:

Yes. Each time a user loads your website, the javascript runs and calls your API to fetch the data.

If you're pulling in data from third party API's, those are still being called each time a user accesses your site, albeit your server may be making the request (depends on your implementation).

If you want to limit your API calls, you will want to store/cache a copy of the API response in a database (or even a text file, depending on size). Your server would then grab the response from your database instead of your other API endpoints.

You have to decide when you want your database data to be refreshed, so your table will need a column for the last time data was fetched.

Every time a user accesses your server's API, will need to check if the data needs to be updated, if not serve them your database copy. Otherwise call your other API, store in database (update time last fetched), then serve that to the user.